# how to delete folders in Azure Gen 2 data lake using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have hard time to delete the folders in the data lake from adf pipeline. I tred similar method as I did for files by using `get metadata` activity and `delete` activity inside `ForEach` activity, could not work it out.

So eveyday I write a snapshot data and file path looks like this -> snapshot/tablename/ date when the file was offloaded -which is basiclayy  GETUTCDATE with this format `yyyyMMddHHmmss`.

so path = `snapshot/tablename/yyyyMMddHHmmss/*.parquet`

My goal is to delete all the folders in the `tablename` folder which is older than 5 days.

any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to delete all the folders in the `tablename` folder which is older than 5 days.

You can achieve your requirement by using Filter activity like below.

First create an integer parameter with `-(n-1)` value where n is the number of days.
Then create a last nth day in `yyyyMMdd` format in a set variable using the below expression.

`@addDays(utcnow(),pipeline().parameters.ndays,'yyyyMMdd')`

[image]

Then use the Get Meta data activity to get the folders list.

**These are my folders:**

[image]

Now, give this Child Items array to Filter activity. Filter activity filters the folder names which are greater than 5 days old.

**Filter items:** `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

**Filter condition:** `@greater(int(variables('last_5thday')), int(substring(item().name,0,8)))`

Filter will give the output array like this.

[image]

Give this array to ForEach as `@activity('Filter1').output.Value` and inside ForEach use the delete activity.

For delete activity, use the dataset parameter for the folder name like below.

[image]

Give `@item().name` as value to the parameter in the delete activity inside ForEach.

[image]

You can see folders which are greater than 5 days were deleted after Pipeline Execution.

[image]

**This is my Pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
"name": "Pipeline 1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Get Metadata1",
            "type": "GetMetadata",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "source_folder",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "fieldList": [
                    "childItems"
                ],
                "storeSettings": {
                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                },
                "formatSettings": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "last_5thday",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@addDays(utcnow(),pipeline().parameters.ndays,'yyyyMMdd')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Filter1",
            "type": "Filter",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "condition": {
                    "value": "@greater(int(variables('last_5thday')), int(substring(item().name,0,8)))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Filter1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.Value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Delete1",
                        "type": "Delete",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "Binary1",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "folder": {
                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "enableLogging": false,
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                "recursive": true,
                                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "ndays": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": -4
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "last_5thday": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "test": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

Comment: hi, where did you define the dataset parameter?

Comment: I lost a track after `"For delete activity, use the dataset parameter for the folder name like below."`  Parameter dataset.folder is not found under this Binary 1

Comment: In the Binary dataset, Go to parameters and create String type parameter `folder` and give `tablename/@{dataset().folder}` in the file path of the dataset as in that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

1. Add a pipeline parameter 'Iteration' with int datatype having value as '-5'
2. Add foreach activity with item expression as `@createArray(1,2,3,4,5)`
3. Inside foreach, add delete activity with wildcard file path `@concat(addDays(utcNow(),add(pipeline().parameters.Iteration,item()),'yyyyMMdd*'),'*.parquet')`

You can tweak the expression according to the filepath if needed.

[image]
[image]
[image]